# Query execution was interrupted, max_statement_time exceeded

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm getting following error via `Microsoft IIS 8' Error Log`:

> Query execution was interrupted, max_statement_time exceeded

MySQL is `5.7.11-log` running on Windows 2012 and per [MySQL :: MySQL Server Version Reference :: 1.5 Option/Variable Changes for mysqld 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-optvar-changes-5-7.html) `max_statement_time` was introduced in 5.7.4 and removed in 5.7.8, but error still there...

This feature with some changes was ported from Twitter MySQL patches [Statement Timeout · twitter/mysql Wiki](https://github.com/twitter/mysql/wiki/Statement-Timeout).

*WITHOUT* switching to [MySQL fork maintained and used at Twitter](https://github.com/twitter/mysql/wiki), what are my other options?

Please advise.

---

*** UPDATE ***

[MySQL Bugs: #81071: Query execution was interrupted, max_statement_time exceeded](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81071)

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing the same issue.
Possible to set the global max_execution_time, but not the session max_execution_time:

```
SET global max_execution_time = 60000;  
SELECT @@global.max_execution_time -- 60000

SET session max_execution_time=300000;
SELECT @@session.max_execution_time -- 15000
```

I used a **hint** as workaround:

```
select /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(300000) */ * from table
where ...
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415905/how-to-set-a-maximum-execution-time-for-a-mysql-query

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem after upgrading my ODBC Connector from 5.2.7 to 5.3.7, but using MS Access.

I manually added the options

```
max_execution_time = 0
```

In my my.ini on server (5.7.10 version) in [mysqld] section. I restarted the server and it worked with the ODBC Connector 5.3.7

**UPDATE**

Today I executed a query that is longer than 60 seconds and the bug is back. Yesterday my queries were running in less 60 seconds (Before adding max_execution_time = 0 to my.ini, neither were they running).

I executed this command in my PC (ODBC 5.3.07):

```
show variables like '%max_execution_time%;
```

Results:

```
max_execution_time  60000
```

obs: 60000 = (60 seconds)

I execute a to configure with 5 minutes

```
SET global max_execution_time = 300000;   
show variables like '%max_execution_time%;
```

Results:

```
max_execution_time  60000;
```

In other machine with ODBC (5.2.7) I execute:

```
show variables like '%max_execution_time%;
```

Results:

```
max_execution_time  300000;
```

In another test:

```
SET global max_execution_time = 0;
```

In my Machine (ODBC 5.3.07);

Results:

```
max_execution_time  60000
```

In the other Machine  (ODBC 5.2.7)

Results:

```
max_execution_time  0;
```

I think this 5.3 driver is frozen with max_execution_time setting to 60000 (60 seconds)